# Relation between Modeling and Simulation(M&S) and Computer Graphics

Tags: graphics, computer-science, simulation

I would like to ask a question about  `Modeling and Simulation(M&S)` and `Computer Graphics`. It might be a silly question but, I am totally lost. I read some articles about modeling and simulation, and tried to make some connections between computer graphics but, they did not help. So, here is the question:

Are modeling and simulation (M&S) and Computer Graphics directly related to each other? It means that I learn a lot about computer graphics if I join a graduate program at a M&S lab or work with a professor who aims M&S?

I know, M&S uses computer simulations but, does developing these simulations really help to specialize in computer graphics?

Answer (score 1):

M&S and computer graphics are not directly related.  However, many M&S applications are written to be graphics intensive.  So the answer to your question depends a lot on what role you want to play.

So what do you want to be? At a very coarse level, you have three (non-exclusive) choices:

1. You can be a modeling platform developer, in which case you probably
   want to know a lot about computer graphics.
2. You can be a model developer, in which case most of the time you'll
   being using somebody else's platform to build your models. You may
   occasionally find a need to build your own models from scratch
   because the available platforms don't do what you need them to.
   Knowledge of graphics wouldn't hurt, but it won't play a major role in your career either.
3. You can be a model analyst. No specialized knowledge of graphics
   required, but the more prob & stats you know the better off you'll
   be, particularly time series.

If you want to span two or more of these, then some knowledge of graphics would be useful, but if you plan to be more of a modeler/analyst you'll be more a consumer rather than a producer of graphics.